# Converting from __m128 to __m128i results in wrong value

Tags: c++, type-conversion, clang, sse, intrinsics

I need to convert a float vector (__m128) to an integer vector (__m128i), and I am using `_mm_cvtps_epi32`, but I am not getting the expected value. Here is a very simple example:

```
__m128 test = _mm_set1_ps(4.5f);
__m128i test_i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(test);
```

The debugger output I get:

```
(lldb) po test
 ([0] = 4.5, [1] = 4.5, [2] = 4.5, [3] = 4.5)
(lldb) po test_i
 ([0] = 17179869188, [1] = 17179869188)
(lldb)
```

As you can see, the resulting integer is.. 17179869188? From 4.5? And why are there only two values? `_mm_cvtps_epi32` should convert 4 packed 32-bit floating-point values to 4 packed 32-bit integers.

Comment: Hint: `4 + 4*2^32 = 17179869188`

Comment: use a printf debugger; `int tmp[4]; _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)tmp,test_i); printf("%d %d %d %d\n", t[0], t[1], t[2], t[3]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugger, in this example, interprets the `__m128i` value as two 64-bit integers, as opposed to four 32-bit ones expected by you. The actual conversion is correct.

In your code you need to explicitly specify how to interpret the SIMD value, for example: `test_i.m128i_i32[0]`

Comment: Yep, that's what's happening. Also, just casting the result also works: `(int32_t)test_i[0]`.